# How do I make a normals shader?

Tags: shader-nodes

I'd like to make a shader that colors everything based off normals.  It's the default shader of all shaders.  How can I make it in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got it.  The "Combine Color" node is a bit confusing to search for.

[image]